# Android Room fallbackToDestructiveMigration by keeping user's data

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have an Android app where I am using prepopulated database from assets.
I would like to know what is the best way to do migrations if I would like to keep user's data and also add any new records from prepopulated database if there are any. (I assume I need to compare records in device's database with prepopulated one)

I have tried fallbackToDestructiveMigration, but this method is just removing device's database and copying new one from assets. (So I am loosing user's data)

The standard migration approach is good, but I don't know how to check during migration if there are new records in prepopulated database and add them to the device's database after migration.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fallbackToDestructiveMigration() method will destructively recreate database tables, ONLY IF the migrations steps that would migrate old database schemas to the latest schema version are not found.

Source: [Room docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#fallbacktodestructivemigration)

In your case, lets say the pre-exisitng version of your DB is 1, and the new one you are going to provide is 2, then your migration steps from 1 to 2 can be as follows:

```
// Create a table for backup
CREATE TABLE myTable_backup(tableId VARCHAR,....);

// Copy old data to this backup table
INSERT INTO myTable_backup SELECT tableId,... FROM myTable;

// Delete old table
DROP TABLE myTable;

// Create the required table with new schema
CREATE TABLE myTable(tableId VARCHAR,....); 

// Insert pre-existing data to your new schema
// Overwrite might / might not happen based on your Primary key strategy
INSERT INTO myTable SELECT tableId,... FROM myTable_backup; 

// Delete the backup table
DROP TABLE myTable_backup;
```

The migration steps can be written as per this [Room docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions).

Comment: Thank you I will try this solution and get back with the results. I think this approach is logically correct and should work with standard migration.